# How to improve performance of iphone application in wifi environment

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, wifi

I have developed an application for iPhone, which is continuously interacting with database ... I have observed that it is running fine in 3G environment but in wifi its performance is not good.

Can someone suggest what can be the reason for it? or can I do anything to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather expect the contrary, given that 3G cellular signal may fluctuate wildly, while WIFI signal should stay almost the same even if you move within the room served by the access point.

The reason may be the particular wireless connection you are using for testing purposes. Try using a different WIFI network and see if the behavior you are experiencing changes.